# UIView.animateWithDuration doesn't apply transform

Tags: swift, animation, uikit

I am trying to create a rotation transition effect between two views. To do that I use scale transform.

My problem is that the first animation is not animated for some reason: the view just disappears. The second animation is performed as expected. Any ideas? Thanks

```
  private func replace(
    _ source: UIView,
    with destination: UIView,
    usingRotationEffect: Void
  ) {
    let collapsed = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0, y: 1)
    let expanded = CGAffineTransform.identity

    source.isHidden = false
    source.transform = expanded

    destination.isHidden = true
    destination.transform = collapsed

    UIView.animate(
      withDuration: 1,
      delay: 0,
      options: .curveLinear,
      animations: {
        source.transform = collapsed
      },
      completion: { _ in
        source.isHidden = true
        destination.isHidden = false

        UIView.animate(
          withDuration: 1,
          delay: 0,
          options: .curveLinear,
          animations: {
            destination.transform = expanded
          })
      })
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known problem that zero scale in CGAffineTransform is not properly animated.
It is because it calculates transform for every frame using matrices and with zero scale factor it's not possible to perform these computations

So, a workaround is to uses **very small, but non zero** value like a:

```
private func replace(
        _ source: UIView,
        with destination: UIView,
        usingRotationEffect: Void
      ) {
        let collapsed = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.0001, y: 1)
        let expanded = CGAffineTransform.identity

        source.isHidden = false
        source.transform = expanded

        destination.isHidden = true
        destination.transform = collapsed

        UIView.animate(
          withDuration: 1,
          delay: 0,
          options: .curveLinear,
          animations: {
            source.transform = collapsed
          },
          completion: { _ in
            source.isHidden = true
            destination.isHidden = false

            UIView.animate(
              withDuration: 1,
              delay: 0,
              options: .curveLinear,
              animations: {
                destination.transform = expanded
              })
          })
      }
```